# Session timeout issue in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, .net-4.0, session-state

I have read some issues related to session time out and i have changed the settings but no avail.

This is entry of session in web.config. i want to expire the session after 5 hours.

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="300" />
```

On Login page i am adding user name in session

```
Session.Add("Authenticated", UserName);
```

and my each page is inherited with BasePage and in base class i have this check for each page.

```
if (Session["Authenticated"] == null)
{
   Response.Redirect("../userlogin.aspx");
}
```

but session expires before one hour.

I want to confirm that during this there is no change in web.config, Bin folder files etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this [ASP.NET Session Timeouts](http://justgeeks.blogspot.com/2008/07/aspnet-session-timeouts.html).

Besides IIS Idle timeout there is Forms authentication timeout, which is 30 min by default. So you will be redirected to the login page before the session actually expired.

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
         <forms timeout="300"/>
    </authentication>

    <sessionState timeout="300"  />
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are hosting it on IIS6 (Win2K3) then go to the settings in the Application Pool in which your application runs. You need to set it there as well.